# Match only strings that start with two letters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use this regex:

```
if (input.matches("(^(?=.*[A-Z]{2}"))
```

But this is not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Do you understand the regex you are using right now?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what should and shouldn't be matched, and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: if Input = TEST123456 --- This Should pass and f Input = T2ST123456  -- this should fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you are using:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Z]{2})" //added the unmatched paranthesis
```

will use *look-ahead* to see if there are two consecutive characters in the range `A-Z` *anywhere* in the string.
To check if the first two are in that range, you can just do:

```
input.matches("^[A-Z]{2}.*")
```

Note that you need the `.*`, since `matches()` must match the entire `input` string to return true.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. this is working fine,i have tested it, what if i want to add [a-z], if in future i get the input string with lowercase letters..

Comment: `[A-Z]` is a character class meaning `one of any element inside []`. To allow more just add them inside the brackets, for example `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean isAlpha(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
}

private boolean startsWith2Alpha(String s) {
    return (s.length() >= 2) && isAlpha(s.charAt(0)) && isAlpha(s.charAt(1));
}
```

So much easier without regexps.

Answer (score 1):

`if(input.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{2}")`

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about non-English language support? `input.matches("\\p{L}{2}.*")` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Hell yeah! The regexp that you have entered does not work because it is not standard one. It should be with A and O characters.